# DataGridview won't update/delete

Tags: c#, database

I'm using an access database in a C# project. I also have a DataGridView to display and edit the table. It works fine when I'm adding a new line but I get an exception when deleting/editting an existing line.
`Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.`
the relavent Code:

```
private void updateB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.complaintsTableAdapter.Update(this.databaseDataSet.complaints);
    this.complaintsTableAdapter.Fill(this.databaseDataSet.complaints);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must set some settings in `complaintsTableAdapter`
in `TableAdpater` set `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete` Command or if you create table adapter automatically from designer can use
`Create method to send updates directly to the database (GenerateDBDirectMethods)`

this can fix your problem